# How to leave matplotlib figure opened after script ends?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Suppose I have the following script plotting a graph for me:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np

img = mpimg.imread('stinkbug.png')
#circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), radius=0.5, fc='y')
circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), radius=100, fill=False, color='b')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(img)
ax.add_artist(circle)
fig.show()
pass
```

Unfortunately, the figure closes after the script ends.

How to prevent that?

**UPDATE**

If it is impossible for the figure to survive the script, then what is the reason for it? What is the connection between the figure and the script?

Comment: Consider accepting an answer if they helped you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The figure created by your script can't survive after the script has ended. But maybe you do not need that, you can make your script wait for you to close the figure window instead. Just be sure interactive mode is not activated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ioff()  # Use non-interactive mode.
plt.plot([0, 1])  # You won't see the figure yet.
plt.show()  # Show the figure. Won't return until the figure is closed.
```

Answer (score 2):

You could save the figure:

```
plt.savefig('my_fig.pdf')
```

Comment: Can I pass `fig` to this function somehow? Or how it knows what to save?

Comment: fig is a child of plt. plt knows what to save.

Comment: What if I have several figs?

Comment: are you having issues? Could you post a simple repeatable example?

Comment: I already went into source code and found that `savefig` delegates to `gcf().savefig()` and prefer to use it...

Answer (score 1):

One way is to keep python opened after running the script.
In order to do that jut include the -i option at the command line. Thus, if your Python script is myscript.py, execute the following at the command line:

> python -i myscript.py

Source: https://www.johnny-lin.com/cdat_tips/tips_pylang/keep_open.html